# checkbox doesnot change value accoding to data , all dates showing same value for checkbox react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when i change the date using input date filed the checkbox value has to change respect to the date but here every date is showing the same value for check box
i have given the entire working code i have tryed in the codesandbox

```
<div>
  <input type="date" onChange={this.dateHandler} />
</div>
```

```
 {this.state.items.map((personData) => {
                return (
                  <>
                    {" "}
                    <div className="activity">
                      <div className="inneractivity" style={styles.gridstyle}>
                        <div style={styles.txt}>
                          <h5>{personData.mainModule}</h5></div>

                        <div style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
                          <div
                            className="aflex-inner"
                            style={styles.gridstyleinner}
                          >
                            {personData.sub_module.map((subModule, key) => {
                              return (
                                <div key={subModule.id}>
                                  <p style={styles.pstyle}>
                                    {" "}
                                    {subModule.subModuleName}
                                  </p>
                                  <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    data-id={subModule.id}
                                    onChange={(e) =>
                                      this.handleCheckClick(e, "items", key)
                                    }
                                    defaultChecked={
                                      subModule.completed && subModule
                                    }
                                
                                  />
                                </div>
                              );
                            })}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </>
                );
              })}
```

entire working code

https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-firefly-rs78v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you share you entire component code?

Comment: @DeanJames do u want the code more than the code in codesandbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for sharing such a complete reproduction!

I'm not sure how the logic should work here in detail--I assume that when clicking the checkbox, the post request saves data to the server, which then gets re-requested later. When it's re-requested, it should have the correct value in the `completed` field for `sub_modules`.

I can spot one issue relating to this behaviour:

```js
prevState[index].completed = e.target.checked;
```

The `prevState` is an array of `personData`. Hence with `prevState[index]` you are finding a `personData` item. If I understood correctly, you want to find a `sub_module`.

This could be done like so

```js
prevState[<personDataIndex>].sub_module[<subModuleIndex>].completed
```

In your render function you are looping in this fashion

```
this.state.items.map((personData) => (
   // ...
   {personData.sub_modules.map((subModule, key) => (
       // ...
       <input onChange={(e) => this.handle(e, "items", key)} />
       // ...
   ))}
))
```

Attempt to provide index values for both of the arrays you are looping

```
this.state.items.map((personData, i) => (
   personData.sub_modules.map((subModule, j) => (
       <input onChange={(e) => this.handleCheckClick(e, "items", i, j)} />
   ))
))
```

And then in the handleCheckClick handler set completed like so

```js
prevState[i].sub_module[j].completed = e.target.checked
```

Also consider using `checked` instead of `defaultChecked` because the input is controlled

```js
<input type="checkbox" checked={subModule.checked} />
```

Another issue with your example was that you were not passing the `date` when you requested the data, but someone else or you yourself already fixed this issue.

Comment: i tryed as u asked but i am now getting error when i click on the checkbox    `prevState[i].sub_modules[i].completed = e.target.checked`  also i think  this line must be j for submodules right?  i have updated the code in codesandbox link so that u can see what i have tryed

Comment: Apologies, my mistake. The correct code is `prevState[i].sub_modules[j].completed = e.target.checked`. I fixed the answer.

Comment: but i am getting error when i click on any check box , i have updated the code in codesandbox link so that u can see what i have tryed

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`   i am getting this error in `prevState[i].sub_modules[j].completed = e.target.checked `

Comment: Sorry, there was another mistake, you are using a field that's called `sub_module` instead of `sub_modules`. --> `prevState[i].sub_module[j].completed = e.target.checked`